# How do you prevent an item from being dragged on a mobile

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

I have an element on the page which use the HTML5 draggable attribute - so it can be picked up and dropped in another column

On mobile, I don't want this to be draggable, so I tried to use this:

```
document.addEventListener("dragstart", dragging, false);

function dragging(e) {
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Which works on a desktop browser shrunk to the size of a mobile, but doesn't work on an actual mobile (dragstart apparently isn't supported on android chrome)

The element just looks like:

```
<div class="card" draggable="true"></div>
```

Setting draggable to false also has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .card {
       pointer-events: none;
    }
}
```

Or add the draggable attr dynamically:

```
 if (!window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) {
     $(".card").attr("draagable",true);
     document.addEventListener("dragstart", dragging, false);  
 }
```

Comment: That works - but also prevents it from being clicked on unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do this with CSS?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .card {
       user-select: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have that on yeah, but it only stops the selection of the text, the item still gets dragged